# How to temporarly disable segue?

Tags: storyboard, segue

I'am using Xcode 4.3.2 with Storyboard and IOS 5.1

In my app, i need to desactivate temporarly a segue (because the form is not complete for example).

Is there a way to do that ? I found nothing about that on google.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I found...

I plugged the segue directly into the cell (normal practice).

But, to control the segue, and in my case, to disable it, we must connect it directly to the view controller.

Then we can - or not - trigger it by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` when we need it!